# Where can I find an ic at home relevant to my project?

Tags: integrated-circuit

I am fairly new to electronics but I have a decent understanding of how basic components work. I want to start building my own audio equipment as fun projects and for actual use in my home studio (going for very unique sounds).

Unfortunately, I do not have access to a credit card and there are practically no decent electronics shops in my country that can provide the variety of parts that I require. I am also university student so I am broke :D. This means I have to salvage old equipment and reuse various components.

Right now I am trying to build an audio amplifier to power four 8 ohm speakers (2 tweets and 2 subs). Where is the most likely place that I can find an ic for my amp at home (aside from other amplifiers)?

Side note: I have one very old car amp, but the components that "looked" like ics don't yield many results on google, and I am really not sure if I can just supplant say an lm3886 chip for any random chip that I found lying around. The component's model is la3607. Also, could someone please tell me if there is a definite way to determine that a particular component IS an ic and what purposes it can be used for without google?

Comment: Without Google you'd need a library of databooks to know what all the different ICs are. Or a different search engine, but that would be cheating.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams So basically there is nothing distinguishing one ic from another aside from the model name?

Comment: @jaja, that's basically correct. And when you go salvaging parts you'll find many ICs aren't labeled with their "real" names but with "house" names used only by the company that built the thing you're salvaging from, and aren't documented in any public documents. (for example, Sony, Toshiba, and LG may all have their own name for the LM7805 and have special 7805's built with their names on them rather than "7805")

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up @ThePhoton . So then, let's say I have googled a component and found it on the manufacturer's site, how will I know if it is a good alternative for another part?

Comment: @Jaja to do that you have to understand what you are designing and what parameters of the device or IC are important for the part to work in your design.

Comment: @ThePhoton Ah, yes I think I understand what you are saying now. Need to know what you want to do before getting the mechanism required to do so.

Comment: What country are you in?

Comment: @RussellMcMahon St. Lucia, West Indies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like to use [Octopart](http://octopart.com) to search for ICs and their datasheets.

To build an audio amplifier, you do not need to use any ICs.  You could start by building a simple BJT amplifier.  It should not be too difficult to find bipolar transistors in random (old) electronics.  Focus on the 3-legged parts.  Look for 8-legged ICs - they may turn out to be op amps.  While you have the electronics in front of you, take a picture of the board (both sides), for later reference.  Try to follow the traces and understand how (part of) the circuit works.  It is a fun thing to do, you learn a lot, and it helps you identify parts.

Comment: Thank you, I researched it and this alternative makes sense and seems simpler even.

Comment: Other giveaways for amps are DIPs with very thick internal pins and veeery long TO-220s (although some of each are motor drivers).